# How to recreate encrypted dm-crypt/LUKS partition with predefined UUID on Linux?

Tags: encryption, luks, uuid, system-recovery, dm-crypt

I have */* and *swap area* of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (and Linux Mint 17.1 LTS) encrypted in dm-crypt/LUKS. */* and *swap area* reside in */dev/mapper/UUID_1* and */dev/mapper/UUID_2*. Is it possible to recreate the */dev/mapper/UUID* (e.g. on the different hard drive) (with the same UUID of course)? It would make recovery of the system with TAR possible in case of disaster. As you know, TAR records UUID of copied partition. Furthermore, grub.cfg, /etc/fstab and initframs contains the number as well.

> sudo tune2fs /dev/mapper/UUID ‐U UUID

command doesn't work.

> cryptsetup luksUUID /device/ --*UUID*

can change only UUID of external container.

Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recreate the *cryptluks* partition with a given UUID, type analogically:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat --verify-passphrase --uuid dec95850-23ad-4f54-b5c2-4f13ea48c571 /dev/sdb4
```

(to encrypt /dev/sdb4 partition with *cryptluks*),

```
sudo cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdb4 sdb4_crypt
```

(to open *luks* container and attach it as /dev/mapper/sdb4_crypt),

```
sudo mke2fs -v -t ext4 -U f65aa2cb-d7a3-4e45-858b-2b12a50e1b45 /dev/mapper/sdb4_crypt
```

(to format *luks* container as *ext4* filesystem and assign a given UUID),

```
mount /dev/mapper/sdb4_crypt /media/<user>/f65aa2cb-d7a3-4e45-858b-2b12a50e1b45
```

(to mount *luks container* under a given path.)

When job is finished, we can unmount the container and close the container:

```
sudo umount /media/<user>/f65aa2cb-d7a3-4e45-858b-2b12a50e1b45
sudo cryptsetup luksClose sdb4_crypt
```

To recreate the swap partition with a given UUID:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat --verify-passphrase --uuid e1baa59a-f24f-450c-a5a8-67f9d2f3338e /dev/sdc2
sudo cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdc2 sdc2_crypt
sudo mkswap -U 5313264e-6212-46f5-936d-f903eb2a2231 /dev/mapper/sdc2_crypt
```

Container can be closed with the command:

```
cryptsetup luksClose sdc2_crypt
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two UUID's for each encrypted partition.

### UUID of file system

Used in `/etc/fstab` and by GRUB (so don't forget use `sudo update-grub` after change). Could be changed with:

```
sudo tune2fs ‐U "<fsUUID>" /dev/mapper/<luksUUID>
```

...where  is UUID of corresponding LUKS partition (could look for it in `/etc/crypttab`) and `<fsUUID>` is file system UUID need to be set. For example:

```
sudo tune2fs ‐U "81db8bc2-6cc1-4272-beab-8c1d667cfa93" /dev/mapper/310919c2-aec9-4641-b3d2-6d523395db34
```

### UUID of LUKS partition

Used in `/etc/crypttab`. Could be changed with:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksUUID --uuid "<luksUUID>" /dev/sdxX
```

...where  is UUID of the LUKS partition need to be set and */dev/sdxX* is LUKS-encrypted device name. For example:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksUUID --uuid "310919c2-aec9-4641-b3d2-6d523395db34" /dev/sda1
```

But it's much better to restore the whole LUKS header (if you're not going to change encryption key). LUKS header does not stores partition size so it could be used to restore to virtually any partition size. Also restoring header is enough for recreation LUKS partition formatting (i.e. luksFormat is not required in this case). Could be done with `luksHeaderRestore` (backup is done with the pretty same way with `luksHeaderBackup`):

```
sudo cryptsetup luksHeaderRestore --header-backup-file "<HeaderBackupFile>" /dev/sdxX
```

...where  is UUID of the LUKS partition need to be set. For example:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksHeaderRestore --header-backup-file "/home/user/MyLuksHeader.Backup" /dev/sda1
```

### Summary

So the restore steps are:

1. Create new partition.
2. Restore LUKS header.
3. Unlock LUKS partition
4. Restore file system using any of these:

   - Restore file system image (e.g. use `partclone`).
   - Recreate file system:

     1. Format new device.
     2. Untar backup.
     3. Restore file system UUID, if required.

### Also

Please note, that using labels for LUKS and file system instead of UUID's could simplify configuration and make it more readable.

Comment: 2  better ideas :  1)  DO NOT USE /dev/mapper/sdXY  in `/etc/fstab` OR `/etc/crypttab`  use  a  line like this: UUID=<fs_UUID>   <UUID>     <fs>  <options>  this  is  much more  robust  especially in the case of  moving  drive partitions / disk.... 2)  look into  cryptsetup-reencrypt  and  run with  the --uuid  switch  (this set a  user-defined uuid for the re-encrypted bits)  ---this is  in-place  reencrypt so if this is  on the  ``system drive`` run this  from a  live media or  other  OS...

Comment: Thanx, but actually 1) /dev/mapper devices was used only with tune2fs utility (it requires device file pathname), assuming we don't need to change anything in system settings, and 2) original question is about backup, not change luksUUID in-place (by the way, luksUUID can be changed without LUKS-volume re-encryption - using `cryptsetup luksUUID`)